# Why is this embedded ruby code evaluating to nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, switch-statement

This code here:

```
<%= case event.subject.value
        when 1
            puts " upvoted"
        when -1
            puts " downvoted"
        when 0
            puts " removed a vote from"     
    end %>
```

does not result in any string being rendered. I tried adding an `else` statement just in case `event.subject.value` had a different value from 1, -1, or 0, but the code still evaluated to nothing. The code throws no errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= case event.subject.value
    when 1
        " upvoted"
    when -1
        " downvoted"
    when 0
        " removed a vote from"     
end %>
```

remove puts statement

Answer (score 2):

puts returns `nil`. It's side effect is that it outputs to the stdout.

Answer (score 1):

"puts" method outputs to your console( server log ), did you try to remove puts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I realized what the problem was. I had to remove the `puts` from the switch statement.